# No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'. In Colab

Tags: neural-network

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Assume that 'ID' is not a feature and 'target' is the column you want to predict
features_train = df_ehr_train.drop(['id', 'readmitted_within_30days'], axis=1)
target_train = df_ehr_train['readmitted_within_30days']

# Standardize the features to have mean=0 and variance=1
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features_train)
features_train = scaler.transform(features_train)

# Split the dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features_train, target_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model(learning_rate=0.01, neurons=1):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(0.001)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())  # Added BatchNormalization
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # Compile model
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Create a classifier with KerasClassifier
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

# Define the grid search parameters
param_grid = {
    'batch_size': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'epochs': [10, 50, 100],
    'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
    'neurons': [16, 32, 64]
}

# Create Grid Search
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

# Evaluate using the best model
best_model = grid_result.best_estimator_
print("Test accuracy:", best_model.score(X_test, y_test))
```

I ran this neural network code and got the error in the title. I was using Colab. Is there any fix?

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-2888c3a9fe5a> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1
      7 from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
----> 8 from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
      9 from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
     10 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'
```

I tried reading other posts and they all said to downgrade tensorflow to 2.8 and keras to 2.6 yet it did not seem to work. And Colab would say you cannot import dtensor api and stuff.